# Laravel - firstOrCreate not persisting all fields to the DB

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the firsOrCreate method to persist records if they already don't exists in the DB. This is my function:

```
  return ContentType::firstOrCreate(
    ['name' => $type], ['slug' => str_slug($type, '-')]
  );
```

The problem I have here is that the new record is created in the DB, but the slug field stays empty. Not sure why is that since the slug is created, because when I do

```
dd(str_slug($type, '-'));
```

Before the method `firstOrCreate()` I do get the slug. 
So, why it is not persisted to the DB?

I have set up in my model the protect guarded array so, that should not be the problem:

```
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];
```

Comment: Shouldn't all the fields be in a single array, i.e.,`['name' => $type, 'slug' => str_slug($type, '-')]` ?

Comment: @apokryfos all those fields which are to be added should be in a single but second array. ([creating models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models))

Comment: @burf At the time I wrote that comment I was working with Laravel 5.3 so was unaware about the syntax with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to ensure that the slug and name properties are fillable.

If your `ContentType` model, ensure the fillable property looked like:

```
class ContentType 
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];
}
```

Comment: But, that is how it is in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent with separate arrays for the column that you want to search the table and  for the array of fields that you want to persist if the model doesn't exist in the DB

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer - I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: Actually, you were right with your first answer, I am working on legacy code, and didn't check the version, as it turns out I have v5.2, where firstOrCreate only takes one array.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `slug` field in your `$fillable` attributes array in your model? Otherwise it won't be inserted due to it being protected:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ContentType extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
    ];
}
```

For anyone else looking, Laravel 5.3/5.4 supports this second array:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L349-L365

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L251-L271

However Laravel 5.2 and below does not:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L243-L260

Answer (score 0):

first setup $fillable in your model as follows:

```
/**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
    ];
```

Then try the following way to insert

```
 $data = array(
    'name' => $type,
    'slug' => str_slug($type, '-')
    ); 

 return ContentType::firstOrCreate($data);
```